# What is the best way to give user access to edit the webite name and other frontend parameters in reactjs?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am building a blog web application. I am using nodejs, reactjs and mongodb. I am trying to create a system where an admin can edit the name of their blog, color, header image, sidebar image and content without contacting the developer which is me.
I started off with the blog name. I used input and react useState and created buttons to handle this change of name. By default, the blog name is welcome, but when the user admin clicks on edit mode button, the input box shows-up and the user can write the preferred name there and click on update to update it. That works until I reload the page and the name goes back to the default state which is 'welcome'.
I am thinking, what is the best way to achieve this? Do I use local storage or the name of the site will have to be loaded from server? Or is there a way to get this done so that when you reload the web app, it doesn't return to the default state but maintain the last name that was saved? I am looking at how WordPress user's can edit frontend parameters of their website and save them.

Here are my codes:

```
 const [EditHeaderTitleMode, setEditHeaderTitleMode] = useState(false) //this actives the edit mode
 const [writeHeaderTitle, setWriteHeaderTitle] = useState('Welcome') //this is the default name of the site.

 return (
    <>
    
 <Dashboard setEditHeaderTitleMode={setEditHeaderTitleMode}/>
    <div className='header'>
      
        <div className='headerTitles'>

            {EditHeaderTitleMode ? <input type="text"
            onChange={(e) => setWriteHeaderTitle(e.target.value)}

            />: <span className='headerTitleSm' >{writeHeaderTitle}</span>}
            <span className='headerTitleLg'>Tech World</span>
        </div>
     
    </div>
    </>
)
```

}

Comment: How about saving it in your database?

Comment: I have been thinking best way to go about this. Will this have it own database model and route path?

Answer (score 0):

When you refresh or reload your Webpage, your component's state will reset to the default value which is 'Welcome' you setted. To avoid this, Get `writeHeaderTitle` from your database And Set `writeHeaderTitle` to the database.

Comment: Okay. That was what I meant by server. Does this mean that everything that will be edited by the user should be saved on the server